# Javascript in acrobate form for setting destination email address

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm trying to use the this.getField code to read a form and set the destination email address. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
form fields are Type, PersonName, PersonStaffNumber and SessionNo. They are all text fields, except PersonStaffNumber which is a number to zero decimal places.

```
var sendForm = app.alert("Confirm you are you ready to submit the form?",2,2,"Submit Validation");

var message1 = "A form has been submitted. See attached.";
var cToAddr = "me@company.com";
var typeAC = this.getField("Type").value;
var candName = this.getField("PersonName").value;
var candNumber = this.getField("PersonStaffNumber").value;
var session = this.getField("SessionNo").value;
var cSubline = "Form submission " + candName;

if(sendForm == 4) {

    if (typeAC === "B757") {
    cToAddr = "757@company.com";
    }

    else if (typeAC === "B767") {
    cToAddr = "767@company.com";
    }

    else if (typeAC === "A330") {
    cToAddr = "330@company.com";
    }

    else (typeAC === "A380") {
    cToAddr = "380@company.com";
    }

this.mailDoc({bUI: true, cTo: cToAddr, cSubject: cSubline, cMsg: message1});

}

else
app.alert("Please continue with the form");
```

The script does not seem to run when past the first pop up alert and "yes" selected.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here. You can't have anything after just an else and you're missing some brackets. The corrected code is below.

```
var sendForm = app.alert("Confirm you are you ready to submit the form?", 2, 2, "Submit Validation");

var message1 = "A form has been submitted. See attached.";
var cToAddr = "me@company.com";
var typeAC = this.getField("Type").value;
var candName = this.getField("PersonName").value;
var candNumber = this.getField("PersonStaffNumber").value;
var session = this.getField("SessionNo").value;
var cSubline = "Form submission " + candName;

if (sendForm == 4) {

    if (typeAC === "B757") {
        cToAddr = "757@company.com";
    }

    else if (typeAC === "B767") {
        cToAddr = "767@company.com";
    }

    else if (typeAC === "A330") {
        cToAddr = "330@company.com";
    }

    else if (typeAC === "A380") {
        cToAddr = "380@company.com";
    }

    this.mailDoc({ bUI: true, cTo: cToAddr, cSubject: cSubline, cMsg: message1 });

}

else {
    app.alert("Please continue with the form");
}
```